# How to start hello world jms app with spring boot and rabbit mq

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-jms

I am reading the following article [SPRING_BOOT_JMS_GETTING_STARTED](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/)

This example explains how to get started with emdedded ActiveMq message broker 
But I already have RabbitMq installed on my PC and I want to use this one.

First of all I enabled the jms rabbitMq plugin

[image]

But I don't see additional exchanges in the management console:

[image]

I expected to see it because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35559811/2674303)

Honestly, I don't understand what should I do right now.

I have a code from Getting Started and I switched on the jms RabbitMq plugin.

Please advice me subsequent steps.

### Small remark:

Garry answer works if I use following gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jms', version: '4.3.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'com.rabbitmq.jms', name: 'rabbitmq-jms', version: '1.7.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exchange won't show up until you actually use it. I just wrote a quick boot app and it worked fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RabbitJmsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RabbitJmsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate template;

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar");
        template.setReceiveTimeout(10_000);
        System.out.println(template.receiveAndConvert("foo"));
    }

    @Bean
    public RMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new RMQConnectionFactory();
    }

}
```

Result:

```
bar
```

Comment: Works fine! foo queue was created automatically

Comment: @Garry I also want to know why example doesn't contain connectionFactory bean definition but for rabbitMq spring doesn't start and say:

Comment: **Parameter 0 of method myFactory in pack.Application required a bean of type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' that could not be found.
 - Bean method 'connectionFactory' not loaded because AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.JndiOrPropertyCondition.Property @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jms.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'; NestedCondition on JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.JndiOrPropertyCondition.Jndi (ad)ConditionalOnJndi JNDI environment is not available
**

Comment: Don't put stuff like that in comments; it's unreadable; edit the question instead. The example uses `spring-boot-starter-activemq` which auto-configures the connection factory for ActiveMQ. You are using JNDI auto configuration which needs a JNDI provider; rabbitmq doesn't provide one; the other answer you pointed to uses the `fscontext` JNDI provider. I think JNDI is overkill in this environment so I just declared the connection factory directly as a `@Bean`.

Comment: @Garry, thanks for your answer. I will follow your advice in future posts. Can you clarify which code line lead to use JNDI auto configuration ?

Comment: It's part of boot's auto configuration "magic". If it doesn't find a connection factory bean (either auto configured, e.g. ActiveMQ) or a user-defined one, it falls back to trying to find one using JNDI. So, the trigger is because you didn't have a `ConnectionFactory` `@Bean`.